# form to select the main image using radio buttons php

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out the best way to process a form which will be used to select the main sponsor (similar to selecting a main image from a collection) and update the database, by replacing the values.

This is the form I'm trying to use to do the update

```
<form action="" method="POST">                
          <table id='partnertable'>
                <tr id='head'>
                    <th id='col4'>Logo</th>
                    <th id='col1'>Partner</th>
                    <th id='col2'>URL</th>
                    <th id='col3'>Actions</th>
                    <th id='col4'>Main Sponsor</th>

                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo1.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>Pure</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://www.pureconcepts.com.mt/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=21'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=21'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='21'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo2.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>wuerth</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://www.wuerth.com.mt/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=22'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=22'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='22'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo3.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>magri cycles</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://www.magricycles.com/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=23'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=23'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='23'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo7.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>powerade</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://www.gsd.com.mt/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=26'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=26'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='26'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo5.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>Scotts</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://www.scotts.com.mt/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=27'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=27'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='27'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo4.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>stop point</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://www.stopshopmt.com/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=28'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=28'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='28'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo6.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>banif</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://www.banif.com.mt/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=29'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=29'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='29'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo8.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>vassallo</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://www.vassallogroupmalta.com/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=30'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=30'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='30'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo11.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>liquigas</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://liquigasmalta.com/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=31'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=31'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='31'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo10.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>attardandco</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://www.attardco.com/aboutus.html</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=32'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=32'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='32'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo9.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>luxuriousM</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://luxuriousm.com/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=33'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=33'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='33'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo12.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>garmin</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://www.garminmalta.com/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=34'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=34'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='34'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr><tr class='details' style='background-color: rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.5);'>

                    <td id='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/mainsponsor1.png'/></td>
                    <td id='col1'>AFSignstudo</td>
                    <td id='col2'>http://www.afsignstudio.com/</td>
                    <td id='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=41'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=41'>Edit</a></td>
                    <input type='hidden' name='partner' value='41'></input>
                    <td id='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4'/>
                </tr></table>               
            <button id="newpartner" type="submit" name="save_partner_btn">Save Main Sponsor</button>
         </form>
```

PHP part

```
else if (isset($_POST['save_partner_btn'])) {
    $partner = (isset($_POST['partner']) ? $_POST['partner'] : null);
    $sponsor = $_POST['sponsor'];

    echo $partner ."<br>";
    echo $sponsor;
}
```

Currently the issue is that the no matter which radio button is selected, the echoed value is '41' (same as the last value).  How can I fix that?

Comment: use are using hidden field partner many times , so the last defined value gets posted.

Comment: all your `<input type='hidden' name='partner'...` have a value set for them, so unsure what you're trying to do here. Plus, does your db column for it set to a default value? Also, `$partner = (isset($_POST['partner']) ? $_POST['partner'] : null);` will never evaluate to NULL since they contain values.

Comment: you tagged as mysql. There isn't any code to support the question, nor does it contain db schema for it. Edit: it has been removed until you can point out relevance for the question.

Comment: You're also repeating a lot of HTML `id`s. This isn't good.

Comment: What @GeoffAtkins is more than not good - *it isn't allowed and will not validate*. Duplicate id's will cause you more problems than you can imagine.

Comment: Yes, in rendering in some browsers, executing any javascript, as well as failure to validate. Sorry, famed British talent for understatement.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     <input type='hidden' name='partner' id='partner' value=''/>
      <table id='partnertable'>
            <tr id='head'>
                <th class='col4'>Logo</th>
                <th class='col1'>Partner</th>
                <th class='col2'>URL</th>
                <th class='col3'>Actions</th>
                <th class ='col4'>Main Sponsor</th>

            </tr><tr class='details'>
                <td class = 'col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo1.png'/></td>
                <td class='col1'>Pure</td>
                <td class='col2'>http://www.pureconcepts.com.mt/</td>
                <td class='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=21'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=21'>Edit</a></td>                   
                <td class='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4' onclick="addHiddenValue('21');"/>
            </tr><tr class='details'>

                <td class='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo2.png'/></td>
                <td class='col1'>wuerth</td>
                <td class='col2'>http://www.wuerth.com.mt/</td>
                <td class='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=22'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=22'>Edit</a></td>
                <td class='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='sponsor' value='4' onclick="addHiddenValue('22')"/>      
            -----
            -----
            ----
```

And in Javascript

```
function addHiddenValue(val){
  document.getElementById("partner").value = val;
}
```

And update its value in javascript or jquery when they choose the radio button

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation, this may work:

```
<form action="" method="POST">                
          <input type='hidden' name='sponsor' value='4'>
          <table id='partnertable'>
                <tr id='head'>
                    <th class='col4'>Logo</th>
                    <th class='col1'>Partner</th>
                    <th class='col2'>URL</th>
                    <th class='col3'>Actions</th>
                    <th class='col4'>Main Sponsor</th>

                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td class='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo1.png'/></td>
                    <td class='col1'>Pure</td>
                    <td class='col2'>http://www.pureconcepts.com.mt/</td>
                    <td class='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=21'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=21'>Edit</a></td>
                     <td class='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='partner' value='21'/></td>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td class='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo2.png'/></td>
                    <td class='col1'>wuerth</td>
                    <td class='col2'>http://www.wuerth.com.mt/</td>
                    <td class='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=22'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=22'>Edit</a></td>
                    <td class='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='partner' value='22'/></td>
                </tr><tr class='details'>

                    <td class='col4'><img id='logos' src='../media/images/logo3.png'/></td>
                    <td class='col1'>magri cycles</td>
                    <td class='col2'>http://www.magricycles.com/</td>
                    <td class='col3'><a href='delete.php?partnerID=23'>Delete</a>|<a href='logo.php?logoID=23'>Edit</a></td>
                    <td class='col4'><input type= 'radio' name='partner' value='23'/></td>
                </tr>
 .
 .
 .
```